# iOS use GSEventSetBacklightLevel, but I lock or unlock iPhone, will become the past brightness

Tags: ios

This is how I set the brightness programmatically, but if I lock and then unlock the iPhone, the brightness level will be reset to the original:

```
GSEventSetBacklightLevel(BrightnessSlider.value);
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setIdleTimerDisabled:YES];
```

So I would like to ask you, how to set the brightness, but also have its new value retained across screen locks and unlocks.

Comment: [UIApplication会会会sharedApplication setBacklightLevel：BrightnessSlider.value];//This code has the same problems

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On iOS 5, you can use the brightness property of UIScreen:

```
[UIScreen mainScreen].brightness = slider.value;
```

Comment: I tried this, but I do of DEB.Use this code directly crashes.

Comment: And the code after the closure of APP on return to their original brightness.I do not know that Google Translate can not let you read.My English is poor, sorry.

Comment: 'I do of DEB' - what do you mean by this?

Comment: Is the jailbreak development.Will add a private API.

Comment: @KID In jailbreak development, you can still use official APIs. Maybe you're not on iOS 5? What's the error message about the crash?

Comment: I know, I used the [UIScreen mainScreen] brightness = slider.value;
iPhone stuck, and then respring

Comment: @KID that should be fine. Could you please install syslogd and show what the error message is?

Comment: The jailbreak develop only real machine debugging. .No Console

Comment: @KID I know, I'm also a jailbreak developer! I mean **install syslogd on your device** and **show the contents of the /var/log/syslog file**!

Comment: So it is, wait a bit, I installed my program.

Comment: I installed syslogd.Also run my program, and respring.But there is no /var/log/syslog

Comment: @KID have you turned it on? There's even an SBSettings toggle for it.

Comment: Did not enter safe mode,Is stuck in one minute, and then respring.

Comment: I no installed SBSettings, I need it?

Comment: @KID it's just one possibility. I start syslogd from there, but i f you know another method to start it, that's also fine.

Comment: Do you have imessage? My imessage:Kidxerw@QQ.com

Comment: All right, I would like to ask if there is no other way to change the brightness?

Comment: @KID I don't know about more.

Comment: You know to shutdown and restart it?  and Thank you very much.

Comment: @KID hold the Home and Power buttons until it reboots.